# mysql Sql inner join 3 tables include rows where table 2 or table 3 is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

mysql question:

I am trying to inner Join multiple tables based on a condition but they are being filtered out if both inner joins don't return something.

For example:

> Select * from TopTable a 
>   inner join SecondTier1 b on a.ID= b.ID and c.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5'
>
> **Let's say this query return 20 records.**

and

> Select * from TopTable a 
>   inner join SecondTier2 c on a.ID= c.ID and c.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5'
>
> **Let's say this query returns 10 records**

Now, I want to combine these results with a single query but if either SecondTier1 or SecondTier2 don't return a value no row is shown.

Something like this doesn't work:

```
Select * from TopTable a 
inner join SecondTier1 b on a.ID= b.ID and b.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5' 
inner join SecondTier2 c on a.ID= c.ID and c.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5'
```

**Instead of returning 30 records, it returns 24 records** removing records where either SecondTier1 or SecondTier2 does not join, but I'd like if SecondTier1 or SecondTier2 has a join to show SecondTier1 or SecondTier2 as null but if they are both null to return no row.

I've tried right join but i'm getting the same results.

Comment: LEFT JOIN is what you need.

Comment: I want no rows to come back if they do not join. Left join will take TopTable rows even if they do not join. I only want TopTable rows if it joins with SecondTier1 on that condition but I also want TopTable rows that join with SecondTier2 condition and if one or the other is joined I want to see it.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM TopTable a 
  LEFT JOIN SecondTier1 b ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Date_Column BETWEEN '2019-2-1' AND '2019-2-5' 
  LEFT JOIN SecondTier2 c ON a.ID = c.ID AND c.Date_Column BETWEEN '2019-2-1' AND '2019-2-5' 
  WHERE b.DateColumn IS NOT NULL OR c.Date_Column IS NOT NULL
```

Note that you would likely use a primary key column in the where clause, but I don't know the schema that you are working with. Also, this was written for sql server, so there could be some very minor differences in the syntax that should be easily accountable for.

(I am assuming there was a typo in the question; your first query wouldn't work with the `c` table in it as you don't do any kind of joins there.)

Comment: You could probably just use b.ID and c.ID in the where clause. Even if they're not the PK, you know they'd have to normally be not null to indicate a join match to have been found.

Comment: @Uueerdo, true, you could use any column that is known to have data, but I tend to use the primary key by convention. 

(On a side note I also never use the primary key named simply ID, this makes it more difficult to know which ID is being referenced in a large query whereas TableNameId will make it simple as it is the same in all usages.)

Comment: This does work but the query execution time is really bad.

Comment: @Watson, yes, LEFT JOIN will almost always have bad execution time. Unfortunately this generally means that a change of schema should be considered to remove the need for the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @dmoore1181 You didn't specify how the tables relate (1:1, 1:N, etc...), but it should be noted that if `c` and `b` are in 1:N relations with `a`, then the number of results will multiplicative (ex: if an `a` record has 3 associated `b` records and 4 associated `c` records, the results will have 12 rows for that `a` record.)

Comment: I can't mark this as an answer - it's unusable. There are 1 million TopTable rows, this is joining all 1 million rows and then filtering. You want to filter the rows first as in an inner join and then you can do additional filtering if you need.

Comment: The only joins that should happen are AFTER you filter the SecondTier tables. So, if 20 rows are found for SecondTier1 in the join filter, you will only join 20 toptier rows with that query. Same with SecondTier2. Which is why i specified inner join. It is the difference between an index range scan and full table scan.

Comment: @Watson if you want to do that, create a temp table, then insert the data into that temp table and read from there.

Comment: @dmoore1181 I undeleted my own answer similar to this one, with an edit that might help with the performance impact. I involves semi-duplicating your join conditions, but should help with the full inspection of TopTable.

Comment: Oops, @Watson see above comment

Answer (score 0):

you can use union

```
select ...
union all
select ...
```

Hope it helps!

EDIT:
Ok, lets say you have 3 columns in select1, and 5 in select2 and you want to display them all together:

```
--returns 3 colums
select col1, col2, col3, null col4, null col5
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id
and date > .....

union all
-- returns 5 columns
select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.id = b.id
and date > .....
```

Know what I mean?
PS: try to organize your cols to be same type

Comment: You are right you can shape the data manually with null columns and then use UNION. It's not as clean as being able to express the query as a series of conditional joins but so far I don't see a way to accomplish my original goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TopTable a 
LEFT JOIN SecondTier1 b on a.ID= b.ID and c.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5' 
LEFT JOIN SecondTier2 c on a.ID= c.ID and c.Date_Column between '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5' 
WHERE ID IN 
   (
      SELECT ID FROM SecondTier1 WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5'
      UNION 
      SELECT ID FROM SecondTier2 WHERE DateColumn BETWEEN '2019-2-1' and '2019-2-5'
   )
   AND (b.ID IS NOT NULL OR a.ID IS NOT NULL)
;
```